# Падеж существительного с глаголом "будем"

Tags: падежи

Допустимо ли сказать: "Мы будем просто зрители" или нужен творительный падеж:" Мы будем зрителями"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше сказать "Мы будем просто зрителями". Форма И.п. устаревает, но раньше она часто встречалась. Например, у Есенина: "Говорят, что я скоро стану знаменитый русский поэт". Считалось, что И.п. выражает устойчивый признак, а Т.п. - напостоянный признак, однако в настоящее время Т.п. фактически вытесняет И.п. во всех значениях. Особенно  актуален именно Т.п. для существительного, выражающего профессию, назначение, состояние, как в данном случае, например:Будете разъездным корреспондентом.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
А вот у Герцена: Ее голос и вид были громкий протест.У Чехова: Будь я подлец и анафема, если я сяду еще когда-нибудь играть с этой севрюгой.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: >Форма И.п. устаревает, но раньше она часто встречалась.  
  
Скорее наоборот. Устаревает творительный. Имхо.
У Есенина - как раз новояз.

Comment: И.п. раньше был в подавляющем большинстве случаев, потом Т.п. его "догнал" и сейчас обе формы равноиспользуемы. Достаточно заглянуть в Нацкорпус и убедиться в этом.

Comment: Голословно. 
>Достаточно заглянуть в Нацкорпус и убедиться в этом.  
  
Да, достаточно заглянуть в Нацкорпус и убедиться в том, что доводы груманта высосаны из пальца. 
Как запрос строить, не сообщите, заглядывающий?

Comment: Начните с первой страницы :  
> С. П. Жихарев. Записки современника (1806-1809)  Ведь надобно же было выдумать такую гиль и разыгрывать ее с такими египетско-чухонскими ужимками и ухватками, что **не будь я приятель** Октавии и Октавиана, то лопнул бы со смеху! 

http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_created&out=normal&kwsz=5&dpp=10&spd=10&seed=&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&text=lexform&mode=main&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E1%F3%E4%FC+%FF

Т.п. - только в конце четвертой страницы. Далее можно считать процент того и другого варианта.

Comment: На первых восьми страницах - только два примера с Т.п. Не поспешил ли бегемотус с обвинениями в голословности? Не высасывает ли он сам свои аргументы из пальцев??

Comment: В корпусе страницы не нумеруются. Или у Вас какой-то другой корпус?
Нумеруются страницы вашего запроса.
А он тенденциозен. Предполагает не глагол "быть", а только сослагательное наклонение. Более того, во всех примерах ("на первых страницах") и по современным нормам положен именительный. Что вообще лишает всякого смысла утверждение о том, что что-то там изменилось. 

Но зато демонстрирует типичный для груманта пример подтасовки. 

Построить же убедительный запрос невозможно.

Comment: А в принципе различие в употреблениях давно описано. 
Постоянное качество обычно требует именительного, временное - творительного. У Розенталя, кажется, все это описано точнее и подробнее. Все примеры это подтверждают.

PS Бегемотус не поспешил. Он вообще не собирается более спешить на помощь севшему в лужу груманту.  
  
> Я дал рабочую ссылку.  
  
На вашей ссылке только ушную лапшу развешивать. Впрочем, это было ясно с самого начала. Вы же ввязываетесь в любой спор только чтобы потом устроить истерику и стререть свои измышлизмы.

Comment: > А **груманьтом** никто и не спорит. Натавил плюсов своими мультами - и сидит в луже.
**Мерзкий грумант**, я раньше сказал про лужу.

>(19 часов назад)behemothus

За то, как бегемотус позволяет себе обращаться к пользователям сайта, я требую его забанить на  ОДИН ГОД.